# Allow PHP inside form

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

I want to allow people to use PHP inside of a textarea of a Wordpress Admin Panel

```
<textarea cols="70" rows="5" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" type="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>" />
    <?php echo stripslashes(get_settings($value['id'])); ?>
</textarea>
```

Will allow HTML usage, however not PHP...

UPDATE:
Let me clarify. I can enter PHP in the form but it wont print on the front-end

```
 <p><?php echo stripslashes($tt_vanity_box); ?></p>
```

Well it's for the footer on a wordpress theme...called "vanity". Where the user can enter copyright info etc. Example:

```
&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <a href="http://mysite.com">My Company</a>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'use PHP' ? you can put *any* type of content in a textarea including PHP

Comment: I think he means he wants people to be able to execute PHP code which is put into a text area.

Comment: On the front end it doesn't display. It get's cleared out...

Comment: Do you want it appended to the page, or actually displayed inside the textbox?

Comment: You know that when you do that, users can do everything, reading databases, reading passwords and everything. What do you want to accomplish

Comment: The only thing I can is that the end of the first line has to be `...type="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>" >` without the `/`. Apart from that I cannot say what you are doing wrong as I don't know the context of your code and what the problem really is.

Comment: Well it's for the footer on a wordpress theme...called "vanity". Where the user can enter copyright info etc. Example
&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <a href="http://mysite.com">My Company</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. After the options panel is saved (with PHP in the textarea) the front-end needs to be buffered (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

```
    <?php $val = stripslashes($tt_vanity_box);
        ob_start();
        eval("?>$val<?php ");
        $val = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $val; 
    ?>
```

Comment: Double check the permission, pale, becose if a normal user will ever have a chance to use this function, he will be able to do whatever he want with the database and php files.